# Selecting an item from list and if one option is selected, deselect all others in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, function, api

I am making a quiz project in ReactJS using Trivia API. If I click one option from 4 options, then it should be selected and simultaneously deselect all other options. Moreover, if I click it again, then it should be deselected.
I am a complete beginner in React. Please help me!!!

```
function Questionnaire(props){
    return(
           <div className="question">
                       <div className="ques">{props.ques}</div>
                       <ul className="options">
                           <li>{props.incorrAns[0]}</li>
                           <li>{props.corrAns}</li>
                            <li>{props.incorrAns[1]}</li>
                           <li>{props.incorrAns[2]}</li>
                       </ul>
            </div>          
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use ```<select></select>```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not supposed to be a coding platform. Please consider learning a bit more about the framework before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use states of the react

```
function Questionnaire(props){
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("")
    
    const setOptions = (opt) => {
        setSelectedOption(opt);
    }
    return(
           <div className="question">
                       <div className="ques">{props.ques}</div>
                       <ul className="options">
                           <li onClick={() => setOptions(props.incorrAns[0])}>{props.incorrAns[0]}</li>
                           <li onClick={() => setOptions(props.corrAns)}>{props.corrAns}</li>
                           <li onClick={() => setOptions(props.incorrAns[1])}>{props.incorrAns[1]}</li>
                           <li onClick={() => setOptions(props.incorrAns[2])}>{props.incorrAns[2]}</li>
                       </ul>
            </div>          
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start, for this kind of assignment I would probably use `<input type="radio">` which you can read about [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp).

But here's a possible solution for you using your code

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Questionnaire(props) {
  const {
    corrAns,
    incorrAns,
    ques
  } = props;

  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState("");

  const handleClick = (answer) => {
    if (answer !== selectedAnswer) {
      setSelectedAnswer(answer);
    } else {
      setSelectedAnswer("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="question">
      <div className="ques">{ques}</div>
      <ul className="options">
        {[...incorrAns, corrAns].map((answer) => (
          <li
            key={answer.id}
            style={answer === selectedAnswer ? { color: "blue" } : null}
            onClick={() => handleClick(answer)}
          >
            {answer}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Questionnaire;
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-water-4vcicf?file=/src/Quiz.js)

Some explanation of what we're doing here, first we destructure `props` so it will be nicer to use. We set a state called `selectedAnswer` that will hold the current selected answer.

I took the liberty to use the `map()` function in order to reduce the number of times you write the `<li>`element by concatenating `corrAns` and `incorrAns` to one array.
We then set an `onClick` function so when you click an answer it triggers the `handleClick` function which checks if you selected a different answer or not, if it's a different answer we highlight the new answer chosen. If the chosen answer is the same as before we just remove the highlight from the answer as requested.